# Oracle connection error on brand new server. But works on others. Unable to load OraOps12.dll

Tags: .net, oracle

I have a fresh new Windows Server 2012r2 box. 
I have a tiny console .NET app that includes the native Oracle client dlls and tries to connect to an Oracle db and just execute a simple query. 
I have 4 other servers that can complete this test. This new machine cannot.

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'OraOps12.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

I tried to enable IIS on the server. no luck.
I confirm the db is pingable from this server.

Not sure what else i can try or how else i can compare the machines that do work. None of these machines has ANY Obstacle software on them.

What else can i try?

Comment: Looks like some Oracle components are not installed

Comment: NO oracle components are installed. that's kind of the point.

Comment: Is the Oracle client the same architecture (32 bit vs. 64 bit) as your IIS?

Comment: yes. all 64-bit

Comment: Do find mentioned dll on your server? Is this folder included in PATH variable?

Comment: that dll is included in my console application. nothing oracle related in PATH.

Answer (score 1):

OraOps12.dll has a reference to the Visual C++ runtime (e.g. version 12.1 has a reference to the Visual C++ runtime 2013). When this runtime has not been installed on your server, the DLL cannot be loaded, and ODP.NET throws this exception.

A tool like Dependency Walker shows you to find missing DLL references and has saved me a lot of time to find missing dependencies on a new server.